# Cohomology with compact support of a closed subspace

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $Y$ be a closed subset of a topological space $X$, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $Y$ and let $j:Y\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion. How to prove that $H_c^i(Y,\mathcal{F})=H_c^i(X,j_*\mathcal{F})$?

Comment: What is the question ? If this is the last equality, then yes. If you know about the functors $f_!$, then it follows from the fact that for a closed immersion $j$, we have $j_*=j_!$ and this functor is exact and preserve injectives.

Comment: How to prove that with compact supports?  If we do not suppose the compact support it follows from what you said and from the fact that given an injective resolution we have $\Gamma(Y,I^i)=\Gamma(X,j_*I^i)$, so their derived functors are the same and so they have the same cohomology. Is this correct?

Comment: The same works with compact support if you use $f_!$ instead of $f_*$. More precisely, let $f:X\rightarrow\{pt\}$, then $f_!\mathcal{F}$ is just the abelian group $\Gamma_c(X,\mathcal{F})$. And we have $(f\circ j)_!=f_!\circ j_!$. Or in other words, $\Gamma_c(X,j_!\mathcal{F})=\Gamma_c(Y,\mathcal{F})$. Now, for every proper map $g$, we have $g_*=g_!$. In particular for a closed immersion $j$, $j_*=j_!$. In particular, it is exact and preserve injectives.